# Find the index of all regex matches in Julia?

Tags: regex, julia

I'm looking for a function that behaves like    matchall() but returns an array containing the match index not the string?

Answer (score 19):

[`eachmatch`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/strings/?highlight=matchall#Base.eachmatch) will give you an iterator over the regex matches.

So then with a list comprehension you could do this e.g.

`[x.offset for x in eachmatch(r"[0-9]","aaaa1aaaa2aaaa3")]`

or this

`map(x->getfield(x,:offset), eachmatch(r"[0-9]","aaaa1aaaa2aaaa3"))`

or even this...

`getfield.(collect(eachmatch(r"[0-9]","aaaa1aaaa2aaaa3")), [:offset])`

All returning:

```
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
 10
 15
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks answer from Alexander Morley.
And you can use `findall()` to get `UnitRange` of regex.

```
julia> findall(r"[0-9]+","aaaa1aaaa22aaaa333")
3-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 5:5
 10:11
 16:18
```

In addition, if you want get string by regex, you can use `SubString()`

```
julia> s="aaaa1aaaa22aaaa333" ;

julia> SubString.(s, findall(r"[0-9]+",s))
3-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "1"
 "22"
 "333"
```

*(Above codes tested on v1.3.0)*